# Resolving a linker error: undefined reference to static class members

Tags: c++, arduino, static-members

My code is Arduinoish.  I turned on verbose compiling so I could verify that all the .o files are indeed getting passed to the linker correctly, and they are (linker command below).  This leads me to believe that it is some sort of syntax error.

Googling for the error "undefined reference to in function" produces a lot of results with answers like "add foo.o to your linker command like so", etc.

I hope the solution is as simple as a missing dot or -> somewhere.

I'm getting this series of errors in one file, from the linker:

```
SerialServoControl.cpp.o: In function `SerialServoControl::send(int, int)':
SerialServoControl.cpp:31: undefined reference to `SerialServoControl::_serial'
SerialServoControl.cpp:31: undefined reference to `SerialServoControl::_serial'
SerialServoControl.cpp.o: In function `SerialServoControl::init(char, char)':
SerialServoControl.cpp:9: undefined reference to `SerialServoControl::_tx'
SerialServoControl.cpp:10: undefined reference to `SerialServoControl::_rx'
```

The .h file:

```
#ifndef SERIALSERVOCONTROL_H
#define SERIALSERVOCONTROL_H

#include "NewSoftSerial.h"

class SerialServoControl {
    public:
          //                             rx, tx
          static NewSoftSerial _serial;//(9, 8);

          int _servo_id;
          static char _tx;
          static char _rx;

          static void init(char tx, char rx);
          static void send(int servo_id, int angle);
          void setup(int servo_id);
          void set(int spot);
};

#endif
```

and the .cpp file:

```
#ifndef SERIALSERVOCONTROL_CPP
#define SERIALSERVOCONTROL_CPP

#include "WProgram.h"
#include "SerialServoControl.h"

//static
void SerialServoControl::init(char tx, char rx){
    _tx = tx;
    _rx = rx;
    _serial = NewSoftSerial(rx, tx);
    _serial.begin(9600);
}

//static
void SerialServoControl::send(int servo_id, int angle){
    unsigned char buff[6];

    int temp     = angle & 0x1f80;
    char pos_hi  = temp >> 7;
    char pos_low = angle & 0x7f;

    buff[0] = 0x80;        // start byte
    buff[1] = 0x01;        // device id
    buff[2] = 0x04;        // command number
    buff[3] = servo_id;       // servo number
    buff[4] = pos_hi;      // data1
    buff[5] = pos_low;     // data2

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        _serial.print(buff[i], BYTE);

    }
}


void SerialServoControl::setup(int servo_id){
    _servo_id = servo_id;
}

void SerialServoControl::set(int angle){
    SerialServoControl::send(_servo_id, angle);
}

#endif
```

The linker command (I've removed the explicit temporary directory paths that the IDE generates for clarity and broken it out to multiple lines.  The actual command is explicit as to the location of all these files):

```
  avr-gcc -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p \
  -o Wheel_Chair_Joystick_Control.cpp.elf \
  SerialServoControl.cpp.o \
  Wheel_Chair_Joystick_Control.cpp.o \
  WheelChairMotor.cpp.o \
  NewSoftSerial.cpp.o \
  core.a \
  -Lbuild277668752723095706.tmp \
  -lm
```

All of these files (SerialServoControl, Wheel_Chair_Joystick, NewSoftSerial, WheelChairMotor) exist in the Arduino [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) directory.  `Core.a` is the compiled AVR library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to define your class statics in a source file some where. Putting them in the class just declares that they are there, but something still needs to define them.

Inside your `.cpp` file your can do so like this:

```
NewSoftSerial SerialServoControl::_serial(9, 8);
char SerialServoControl::_tx = 0;
char SerialServoControl::_rx = 0;
```

Put appropriate initial values; I just assumed the comment was for the constructor.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response.  I can easily set _tx and _rx to zero in the CPP file as an initialization, but I would like to be able to delegate the pin numbers to _serial constructor from main().  I've tried converting _serial to a pointer and filling the pointer in my init() method, but it didn't resolve the problem.  Any suggestions?

Thanks again!

Comment: You can still have an `init` function, hen you might need an `init` function on `NewSoftSerial` as well. Using a pointer should also solve your problem; you'd have to create the object in the `init` function.

Comment: aha!  I believe I have it sorted now.  Thank you again for your prompt help.  I'm still a bit green on the C++ front, but I'm learning quickly.  I'm uploading the code for testing now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create memory and initialize your static variables.

In your CPP file add the following:

```
NewSoftSerial SerialServoControl::_serial(9, 8);
char SerialServoControl::_tx = 0;
char SerialServoControl::_rx = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the value _serial is static, it exists when an object isn't instantiated.
This means that you **must** declare it in the code as

```
NewSoftSerial SerialServoControl::_serial(9, 8);
char SerialServoControl::_tx = 0;
char SerialServoControl::_rx = 0;
```

which has already been suggested.

If you then want to change it in the init function, you simply have to change your `_serial = ...` line to `SerialServoControl::_serial = NewSoftSerial(tx, rx).`
Of course, this means you'll have to define a relevant constructor for the NewSoftSerial  class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is somewhat dead, but in my case I forgot to define the methods I was referencing, imagine that.......

Yes they were DECLARED, but when I checked my .cpp file, there was no definition for them, so this time the error was literal.